# Designing a hierarchy of abstract classes and using it in EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET Core with Entity Framework Core to build a finance app and I want to know how to make my design better.

I have a 1 to Many relationship between two entities, `BankAccount` and `Transaction`. In a way that:

- 1 Account can have many Transactions
- 1 Transaction Belongs to 1 Account

However, I want to include bank accounts and transactions coming from different 3P sources. And while this relationship and the main fields are common across different sources, each source has a unique set of properties I want to keep.

To achieve this I decided to define these entities as abstract classes. This way, you can only instantiate concrete versions of these entities, each coming from a particular data source.

```
public abstract class Transaction : BaseEntity
{
    public DataSource Source { get; private set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public BankAccount BankAccount { get; private set; }
    public Guid BankAccountId { get; private set; }
    ...
}


public abstract class BankAccount : BaseEntity
{

    public DataSource Source { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Balance Balance { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Transaction> Transactions {get; private set;}
    ...
}
```

Here is a trimmed down example of the concrete implementations:

```
public class PlaidTransaction : Transaction
{
    public string PlaidId { get; private set; }

    private PlaidTransaction() : base() { }

    public PlaidTransaction(decimal amount, DateTime date, string name, Guid bankAccountId, string plaidId) : base( amount, date, name, bankAccountId)
    {
        PlaidId = plaidId;
    }
}

public class PlaidBankAccount : BankAccount
{
    public string PlaidId { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

I am using .Net Core with Entity Framework Core to persist my data and I managed to store my concrete classes all in the same table [(TPH approach)](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy)

This works great and now all my entities live under the same table. So I can either query all Transactions or those of a certain type using LINQ's `OfType<T>` extension.

```
DbSet<Transaction> entities = _context.Set<Transaction>();

IEnumerable<PlaidTransaction> plaidTransactions = entities.OfType<PlaidTransaction>();
```

However, when I access my BankAccount field from my concrete Transaction I don't get the concrete instance. So something like this doesn't work.

```
plaidTransactions.Where((t) => t.BankAccount.PlaidId)
```

Instead I have to cast it:

```
plaidTransactions.Where((t) => (t.BankAccount as PlaidBankAccount).PlaidId)
```

What can I do to avoid casting everywhere? I feel there's a missing piece in my design that would make all my code easier. I was thinking of overriding the getters on my concrete classes but I don't know if I can return a derived class to a base class method. Maybe I should move to generics but 1) I still want to keep the fixed relationship between these entities and 2) how would EF Core handle this?

Comment: why do you need the base classes?

Comment: I'm thinking that base classes allow me to standardize and reuse code. By having a base Transaction class for example, I can be sure that all transactions, regardless of their source have an amount.  That way, if I want to know how much money I spent last month over all my accounts it would be as simple as iterating a Transaction list and adding up. I guess I want to decouple my entities from their source. What do you have in mind? @jgauffin

Comment: i'm thinkning YAGNI. You are making things complex without having a reason to do that. Keep it simple now and refactor once you have a specific requirment.

Comment: That's a great point. In this scenario though, supposing I move away from inheritance, would you recommend having one transactions table per data source and treat them all as different entities?

Comment: why do you need one transaction table per data source?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following it right, but If we're talking about integrating external systems, one good approach is to keep strict boundaries around your own business domain, and utilize adapters to adapt external data to your own domain entities. Maybe you could have a generalized BankAccount entity, with a property that specifies the data source. And, if additional fields are needed for a given data source (or the full received payloads for reference), those could be stored in a separate table, connected through the BankAccount Id. That is, if I understood it correctly. :)